# Using bosun for alerting on influxdb events

Tags: influxdb, bosun

I have an influxdb which has metrics being updated every few minutes. I would like to use bosun to alert me for any anomolies with my data. Is
it possible to do this? Or do I need to setup an scollector (which I want to avoid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bosun does not require scollector to be useful. You can definitely just make alerts from your existing influx install.